# Dimensional Regularization for $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

When using dimensional Regularization for $\phi^4$ theory to calculate the running of the mass, why there is no quadratic divergence as expected?

For details, see Prof. Arttu Rajantie, [*Lecture notes in Advanced QFT*](http://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/theoreticalphysics/Public/MSc/AQFT/AFTnotes.pdf), page 51, equation 333 and 334.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details?

Comment: @Prahar you can look at the link to the notes

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int \frac{d^{4}p}{p^{2} - m^{2}}$ in dimensional regularization is
$$
I(d, m^{2}, \mu^{2}) \sim \frac{\Gamma \left( 1-\frac{d}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (d)}\left(m^{2}\right)^{\frac{d}{2}-1}\mu^{4-d}
$$
There is the problem with integral since there is no properly defined $\Gamma$ function of negative argument. We, however, "drops" the quadratic part. Why? The reason is hidden in analytic continuation procedure. Let's use the trick. Suppose you calculate integral
$$
\tag 1 \int d^{d}p\frac{d}{dp} \cdot (pf(p)) =\int d^{d}pp \cdot \frac{d}{dp}f(p) + d\int d^{d}pf(p),
$$
where
$$
f(p) \sim \frac{1}{p^{2}-m^{2}}
$$
The left handside of this equation is surface term, which contains the quadratic divergence. However, the analytic continuation procedure ignores surface terms, and thus the left handside of the integral may be dropped. Thus you have that
$$
d\int d^{d}pf(p) = -\int d^{d}pp \cdot \frac{d}{dp}f(p),
$$
and the right handside is just
$$
\sim \int \frac{d^{d}p}{(p^{2}-m^{2})^{2}}\sim \Gamma \left(2-\frac{d}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: will dropping the quadratic part yields distinct scale dependence of the mass renormalization, thus giving different $\beta$ function(mass anomalous dimension)?

Comment: @user3229471 : in general - yes, since mass anomalous dimension and beta-function are scheme dependent. For simplicity, suppose you assume two different regularization scheme in massless, but you use the one scale $\mu >> m$ (by using correspondence between two schemes of regularization). Because of that, the difference in two schemes only leads to redefining the couplings, $g \to \tilde{g}(g)$, and this will lead to following changing of $\beta$-function:

Comment: $$
\tilde{\beta} (\tilde{g}) = \beta (g)\frac{d\tilde{g}(g)}{dg}
$$
However, in $\varphi^{4}$ theory coefficients near first two terms of $\beta$-function expansion in $g$ ($\tilde{g}$), $g^2, g^3$, are the same for arbitrary regularization scheme.